# using moment-countdown.js plus countdown.js always throw Uncaught TypeError: moment(...).countdown is not a function

Tags: momentjs

I am using [moment-countdown.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-countdown) to make a countdown timer like this:

```
let deadline = '2019-03-13T17:46:08Z';

function () {
  let timeRemaining = moment().countdown(new Date(deadline).toString(), countdown.DAYS | countdown.HOURS |
                            countdown.MINUTES | countdown.SECONDS);

}

setInterval(() => this._computeTimeLeft(), 1000);
```

It seems work fine, but keep throwing an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: moment(...).countdown is not a function

Anyone have an idea about this? Thank you so much!